# Post AngularCli does not work

Tags: typescript, http, post, angular-cli

AngularCli folks

For some reason my post of adding new object/input to my mockApi does not work, at least my Api stays unchanged. 
Is there something wrong with my code or why won't it work?

Let me know if there are further details needed.

**add-to-api.component.html**

```html
 {{diagnostic}}
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Add to Api</h1>
      <form (ngSubmit)="addToApi(devicemgForm.value)" #devicemgForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="hitInfo">HitInfo</label>
          <!-- HitInfo är Name i guiden -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hitInfo" required [(ngModel)]="model.HitInfo" name="hitInfo" #hitInfo="ngModel">
          <div [hidden]="hitInfo.valid || hitInfo.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Fältet måste fyllas i</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="repairStatus">RepairStatus</label>
          <!-- RepairStatus är Alter Ego i guiden -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="repairStatus" required [(ngModel)]="model.RepairStatus" name="repairStatus" #repairStatus="ngModel">
          <div [hidden]="repairStatus.valid || repairStatus.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Fältet måste fyllas i</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="reported">Reported</label>
            <!-- Reported är powers i guiden -->
            <select class="form-control" id="reported" required [(ngModel)]="model.Reported" name="reported">
              <option *ngFor="let rep of reported" [value]="rep">{{rep}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>


        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!devicemgForm.form.valid">Submit</button> -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!devicemgForm.valid">Submit</button>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="devicemgForm.reset()"
           >Rensa formulär</button>

      </form>
  </div>
```

**Next the add-to-api.component.ts, this component is a part of another component via a router-outlet/routerLink so there are more imports than are visible in this .ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Devicemg} from '../devicemg';
import { GetApiService } from '../get-api.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-to-api',
  templateUrl: './add-to-api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-to-api.component.css']
})
export class AddToApiComponent implements OnInit {
  kurtan = [];
  reported = ['true', 'false'];

  model = new Devicemg ();


  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }

  constructor(private _getApiService: GetApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


    addToApi(devicemg: Devicemg) {
      this._getApiService.addApi(devicemg).subscribe();
    }

}
```

**The service class I use get-api.sevice.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Devicemg } from './devicemg';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    // 'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class GetApiService {

  // private mainmenuUrl = 'https://logmanagementtool.azurewebsites.net/api/loganalysis/getall';

  private jMockApi = 'http://demo8609839.mockable.io/johansmockapi';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getApi(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.jMockApi)
    .pipe(map((response: Response) => response));

  } // ska inte ha .json() på slutet då detta görs automatiskt nuförtiden på Response i angular


  public deleteIdFromApi (id: number): Observable<{}> {
    const url = this.jMockApi + '/' + id;
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.jMockApi, httpOptions).pipe(map((response: Response) => response));
  }


  public addApi (devicemg: Devicemg): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Devicemg>(this.jMockApi, devicemg, httpOptions);
  }


}
```

**app module**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DevicemgComponent } from './devicemg/devicemg.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';

import { GetApiService } from './get-api.service';
import { AddToApiComponent } from './add-to-api/add-to-api.component';

// import { bootstrap } from


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DevicemgComponent,
    AddToApiComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [GetApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any help in understanding why it doesn't change my api: http://demo8609839.mockable.io/johansmockapi

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console when you run this?

Comment: Nothing in console but when I debug and hover over som elements I get some errors. 
For instance in add-to-api.component.ts when I hover over the function name addToAp(....  I get ReferenceError: GetApiService is not defined at eval